# vba Macro to open other WB and execute Macro fails when other WB have userform show on opening

Tags: vba, excel

As topic implies I have a problem I cannot find any solution to.

I have a Workbook (1) with the purpose to open other WBs and run macros in them.
Everything works like a charm except when the other WB has `Workbook_Open()` event to open a Userform (typically it asks if the WB should be updated). Then I get error code 1004 and my code fails.

How could I supress the `Workbook_Open` event from triggering when I open another WB?

I have tried the setting `Application.EnableEvents = False` but it´s not related.

Thank you very much for any help on this topic!

Here is the code for opening the WB

```
Public Function wbTargetOpen(sTargetPath As String, SPassword As String) As Workbook

Dim sWBName As String

sWBName = Mid(sTargetPath, InStrRev(sTargetPath, "\") + 1, Len(sTargetPath) - InStrRev(sTargetPath, "\") + 1)

If WorkbookIsOpen(sWBName) Then

    Set wbTargetOpen = Workbooks(sWBName)

    If wbTargetOpen.ReadOnly = True Then
        wbTargetOpen.Close
        Set wbTargetOpen = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=sTargetPath, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False, WriteResPassword:=SPassword)
    End If

Else
    Set wbTargetOpen = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=sTargetPath, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False, WriteResPassword:=SPassword)
End If

If wbTargetOpen.ReadOnly Then sErrorCode = "ReadOnly"
```

End Function

Comment: please show the code, with which you open the other Workbook so we can see, where the matter is.

Comment: Code is added. It´s not any problem opening a WB that doesn´t have any Workbook_Open event occuring and then execute the macro. My problem is only when target WB has Workbook_Open event to show a userform. Thanks!

Comment: And adding a the Application.EnableEvents = False phrase before the the open procedure didn't do the trick? What do you mean with "it's not related"?

Comment: I got past the first obstacle. The second is that the called macro in target WB displays a msgbox. I need to press "ok" to proceed with next wb. Is there any way to supress this without chaning in targetWB VBA? @JulianKuchlbauer

Comment: AFAIK, no. The only way i think could work is to edit the code of the second WB on the fly before calling the macro and reverting the change / closing without saving.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is add one word `VbModeless` to the other workbook which launches the userform.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

The `vbModeless` will launch the form but will also allow your macro to run.

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer not changing anything in TargetWbs VBA code. I solved it with Thomas solution.

Comment: Sure no problem. :) It's your call

Comment: I just saw you reply in the other post. Now you are ready to make the change for the msgbox? LOL... Anyways... like I said, it is your call

Answer (score 1):

### Close the other userforms before you run the macros.

```
Sub CloseOtherUserForms()
    Dim frm As UserForm
    For Each frm In UserForms
        If Not TypeName(frm) = "MacroForm" Then
            Unload frm
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Neat solution! Thanks. Now I managed to get past the first obstacle. The second is that the called macro in target WB displays a msgbox. I need to press "ok" to proceed with next wb. Is there any way to supress this without chaning in targetWB VBA? @ThomasInzina

Comment: I know that you don't want to change anything in the target workbook but it would be far easier then trying to close that Msgbox.  I would add an optional parameter to the macro `Optional ShowMessageBox as Boolean = True"  ans then I would surround the Msgbox in an `If ShowMessageBox Then` statement.  You would call the macro like this:  `Application.Run "'example.xlsm'!MyMacro", True`.  With this setup you can be assured that the target workbook will function normally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this will be the best solution to implement in targetWb!

Comment: One more question @ThomasInzia. Why would creating a new Excel.Application solve this problem?

Comment: @EliasGröndal I just test it in VBScript and Excel VBA ; in both instances, code execution stopped to wait on the MsgBox.  Application.OnTime even waited for the MsgBox to return.